# YII: How authenticated user details are stored in session

Tags: php, session, yii

I am new to this framework.

I need to implement authentication using google.

So I wanted to know how this framework stores the authenticated user details in session.

I printed the session but I saw some different session variable name.

I want to know how it is created.

Following is the session array:

```
[e7ebc265ca1cd5fe8c265ca60cecda89__id] => 3
[e7ebc265ca1cd5fe8c265ca60cecda89__name] => david
[e7ebc265ca1cd5fe8c265ca60cecda89__states] => Array
    (
    )
```

Comment: If you are new then my advice is to start using Yii 2. Yii 1 is good but Yii 2 is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can used **setState** and **getState** for accessing session value in yii.

**setState:**

```
 Yii::app()->user->setState('userId', $user->id);
 Yii::app()->user->setState('username', $user->username);
 Yii::app()->user->setState('userEmailAddress', $user->email_address);
 Yii::app()->user->setState('userFullName', $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name);
 Yii::app()->user->setState('gender', $user->gender);
```

**getState:**

```
Yii::app()->user->getState('userId');
Yii::app()->user->getState('username');
Yii::app()->user->getState('userEmailAddress');
Yii::app()->user->getState('userFullName');
Yii::app()->user->getState('gender');
```

OR You can access session data.

```
Yii::app()->user->userId;
Yii::app()->user->username;
Yii::app()->user->userEmailAddress;
Yii::app()->user->userFullName;
Yii::app()->user->gender;
```